# Find marginal distribution

Tags: probability, distributions, marginal-distribution, calculus

The random vector $(X,Y)$ is uniformly distributed over $$D=\{(x,y): 0 \leq x \leq 2 , 0 \leq y \leq 2-x\}.$$ Find the marginal distribution of the random variables $X$ and $Y$.

For the radom vector $(X,Y)$ we have $$f_{(X,Y)}(x,y)=\frac{1}{2}$$ for $(x,y) \in K$ and $$f_{(X,Y)}(x,y)=0$$ otherwise. Then,

$f_X(x)=\int_{0}^{2-x}\frac{1}{2}dy=1-\frac{1}{2}x$ for $x \in [0,2]$ and $f_X(x)=0$ otherwise.

$f_Y(y)=\int_{0}^{y+2}\frac{1}{2}dx=1+\frac{1}{2}y$ for $y \in [0,2]$ and $f_Y(y)=0$ otherwise.

I kindly ask for confirmation if my solution is correct.

Comment: One easy check is to integrate the answers to confirm they are both $1.$  (They are not.)  I warmly recommend drawing pictures of this setting and the operations you are performing.

Comment: Thank you. Could you please tell me where I am doing wrong? Is the pdf of $(X,Y)$ correct?

Comment: Drawing the picture will make the problem obvious.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In deriving the marginal distribution of y, x should go from 0 to 2-y.

Comment: Of course... Now everything is clear. I did not notice that I had incorrectly rewritten the boundary of the integral. Thank you very much!

Comment: Np. Sometimes it can be tricky to "debug" your own work :)